# 404 Error with Zelle APIs in Consumer Suite

Tags: http-status-code-404, banno-digital-toolkit, zelle

I'm experiencing difficulties with the Zelle APIs from Jack Henry's Consumer API suite. Every time I try to access them, I encounter a "404 Not Found" error, despite being able to use the other APIs in the suite without any issues. Has anyone else faced similar challenges, or successfully connected to the Zelle APIs?

Here's the API documentation I'm referring to:
https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/zelle/details/

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to this issue. Thank you!

This problem persists across all Zelle APIs. For instance, when I use the following endpoint, I receive the same error: "404 Not Found"

${config.api.environment}/a/consumer/api/v0/users/${user_id}/zelle/accounts

Comment: It looks like the `GET /users/{userId}/zelle/accounts` returns an HTTP 404 Not Found, but it's ambiguous if that means that the userId is incorrect OR if the userId is correct but the user isn't _enrolled_ in Zelle. Which leads to the natural question of 'is your user actually enrolled in Zelle?' Also, there is an enrollment check endpoint which may help clarify the situation: `GET /users/{userId}/zelle/enrollment`.

Comment: Thank you Jamie. Yes the user already enrolled in Zelle and can transfer money. I tried enrolment endpoint and that gives me the same error. All the Zelle APIs give me same 404 error.

Comment: I tried with a user who is not enrolled in Zelle and I see 403 error for that user. Documentation refers to 403 as "disclosure acceptance required or no ability". I see this even for enrollment endpoint.

Tried multiple users who already enrolled in Zelle and I get 404 for all the users who are already enrolled and 403 for users who are not enrolled. This only happens with Zelle endpoints. I don't have any issue with all the others.

Comment: Double-checking, are you ensuring that the auth URL includes the specific OAuth scope for the specific endpoint you are using? e.g. for `GET /users/{userId}/zelle/accounts` it is `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/zelle.accounts.readonly` and for `GET /users/{userId}/zelle/enrollment` it is _either_ `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/zelle.contacts.readonly` or 
`https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/zelle.tokens.readonly`. Also, the user needs to _consent_ for the OAuth scopes to actually enable access to the endpoint.

Comment: Yes I do have right score in place. The way my external application is setup, user consent is not required. As this is not a third-party app and we are working on it internally within CU, we did not have user consent needed.
Not sure why the issue is just with Zelle endpoints. I am able to access Bill Pay, Transfers, Cards etc., all the other API endpoints with no issues.

Comment: Can you get an `x-request-id` from the response headers along with the date + time of the request? That'll make it easier to share with Engineering so they can look at the logs.

Comment: Below are the headers from response. This is for "zelle/enrollment" endpoint. Hope this helps. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Response Headers: {
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '0',
  date: 'Wed, 29 Nov 2023 23:52:52 GMT',
  'x-b3-sampled': '1',
  'x-b3-spanid': '0f12d39edba6e580',
  'x-b3-traceid': '06f36ba46fcee9655160c4706451c4b5',
  'x-request-id': '0f89f9a6f60b8b2655dfbe451e2fffa5'
}

Comment: Thank you for the info. We'll share this with Engineering to get some insight into what's happening.

Comment: Jaime, did you hear back from your Engineering?

Comment: We're awaiting a patch from Engineering but do not have an ETA.

Comment: Engineering has deployed a patch. Please try again. If you encounter issues, please include the date/time and `x-request-id` from the response header.